# Using the tumblr api how do I return a permalink?

Tags: tumblr

If I used the api to post, I would like to return back the Tumblr permalink for that site I sent it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post via the API the **postId** will be returned. So you just append **/post/{postId}** to the blog's URL to get the permalink. This URL will not include the slug but the slug is just for easier reading. If you added a custom slug then just append it to to the URL.

To get the blog's URL do an API call to **api/authenticate** and it will return the URL for all the public blogs of that account, including the one you posted to.

Comment: no problem, glad to help :)